# Statistical test for checking stationary/non-stationary of a categorial time series

Tags: statistics, time-series

I am searching for a statistical test for checking if a categorial (nominal) time series is stationary or not, however, all the tests I have found so far (Dickey-Fuller, Priestley-Subba Rao (PSR), Wavelet Spectrum) are for real values. Does someone know such a test for categorial data?

e.g., the series= ['dog','cat', 'mouse',....,'dog','rabbit','cat'....] is an example for the series I deal with.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think the notion of stationarity applies directly to these kinds of series.

What if you turned this into a multivariate binary time series, and modeled it like that?

Comment: Do you mean encoding each observation ('dog', 'cat' etc) as a binary vector and apply the stationary test on this series of binary vectors?

Comment: I'm not familiar with time series analysis of binary data, so you should definitely do some independent research.

Answer (score -1):

Try encoding the set of all categorical labels into real values and then use one of the listed tests. I believe One-Hot encoding should do just fine.